# How can I set a hidden parameter to a value in Module?

Tags: differential-equations, functions

Here is a minimal example:

```
    x = 4 + m;
    g = Sin[x];
    Module[{m = 1}, g]
    
   Sin[4 + m]
```

So, why is m not replaced inside `Module`?

I know that I can solve this by setting  `g[m_] = Sin[x]`, but are there any alternatives to do that without redefining `g`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Module` does *lexical* scoping. That means that only the `m`s that are literally inside the module when it is evaluated are bound to the `m` of the module, other `m`s outside of the `Module` are unaffected (this is effectively done by replacing all occurrences of `m` in the body of the `Module` with a localized name like `m$1234`, which is then set to `1`). In your case, the body of the `Module` is `g`, which does not contain `m`, so nothing happens.

As you have already noted, the best way would often be to pass in the value as a parameter. Another option is to use [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html), which does *dynamic* scoping. This means that any `m` that is encountered while the body of the `Block` is evaluated is evaluated to `1` (this is effectively done by temporarily setting a global value to `m`):

```
x = 4 + m;
g = Sin[x];
Block[{m = 1}, g]
(* Sin[5] *)
```

Comment: thanks @Lukas Lang, exactly what I was looking for. Now, I see where I should use `Block`, `With`, and `Module`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful:

```
x = 4 + m;
g = Sin[x];
Module[{m = 1}, Evaluate[g]]
```

The output is

```
Sin[5]
```